# Does .NET connectionManagement config setting apply to all .Net apps?

Tags: .net

I've read every article I can find on the `maxconnection` setting in `connectionManagement`: i.e. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268/en-us, but there's lots of confused use of terminology between ASP.NET and .NET.

Does this setting apply only to ASP.NET or does it also apply to .NET console apps/windows services?

Answer (score 4):

From  [Element (Network Settings)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6484zdc1.aspx):

> The  Element (Network Settings) element contains settings
>   for classes in the System.Net and related child namespaces. The
>   settings configure authentication modules, connection management, mail
>   settings, the proxy server, and Internet request modules for receiving
>   information from Internet hosts.

So for example the maxConnection setting applies to any attempt to make outbound connections using WebRequest or it's subclasses (HttpWebRequest, FtpWebRequest, etc.). ASP.NET is a layer over the core framework so these settings apply to it and all other types of applications such as Windows.Forms and console apps.

To confirm I have personally had to set this setting for console, winform and ASP.NET apps to increase the maxConnection limits when doing load testing.

Example usage:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="1000"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Also check that the server being connected to is using HTTP keep-alive if you are creating lots of short lived connections to the same URL, e.g. if making SOAP service calls. This will allow calls to re-use the same connection. If you don't do this then you can exhaust the available TCP ports on machine making the outbound calls, because once used they don't become immediately available for re-use (this point is really only relevant for high load or load testing set-ups).

Comment: Hmm thanks, it still seems to be limited. Will these settings work in `app.config` or does it have to be `machine` level? Could you provide me an example of settings you've used that work?

Comment: app.config for non-web applications, for anything hosted in IIS or the basic visual studio web hosting you need a web.config.